# I'm locked out of my python program, Linux operating system, after auto start-up employed

Tags: linux

I'm using a small Linux computer in which the software is on an sd card. I needed a program to run at start-up, so I did sudo nano /etc/rc.local and then I added a new line btwn F1 and exit 0 that contains the complete path to my program. This works great, but now I'm locked out. My program runs at start-up like I wanted, but I need to access the program and tweak a few things. I did try putting the sd card in my desktop Windows computer and add init=/bin/sh to the end of the cmdline.txt file. But this had no effect, any suggestions?

Comment: You should find the filesystem (usually ext2/ext3/ext3 or fat), used on the SD, and then find way to access this filesystem. Easier way is to get Linux (try linux livecd/liveusb), and harder is to find linux fs reader for windows (there are some, and several may support file writing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, boot up a desktop Linux machine - mount the sd card, edit the `/mnt/etc/rc.local` to remove the newline and complete path to your program (from between `F1` and `exit 0`). Then `umount` the sd card and boot it up. If it won't boot, try and undo that edit to `cmdline.txt` (which I don't think actually does anything - being a txt file).

Comment: Regarding cmdline.txt: Assuming this is an embedded board, the file may be read by the bootloader to set the appropriate kernel arguments (although for U-Boot its usually called uEnv.txt).

Comment: @fbrozovic I realize that's potentially the case. Which is why I suggested undoing the change if it still won't boot. Anyway, he didn't post anything on the actual board or embedded distro so we can't really say more (other then if he made a change on Windows, and it worked it might be "loadlin").

Answer (score 0):

This question probably belongs on Super User rather than here.

However, it would probably be easiest for you to get access to a Linux PC and try to edit the file there rather than on the embedded board itself.